# Masonry Container - 2 columns treated as 1 on some media queries (leads to big gap at bottom)

Tags: css, responsive-design, multiple-columns, jquery-masonry, sticky-footer

My website uses a masonry container. It works fine on full screen.  As it sizes down (responsive), some @media queries work as designed, some don't work. Here is the behavior of the ones that don't work:

As you scroll to the bottom, there is a very large gap before it will trigger the loading of new images/boxes. It appears as if one of the containers is calculating its height as if all the images/boxes were in a single column, where in fact, they are still displaying in two columns. The result is the height of the container is double the height of the two columns and you have to scroll to the very bottom to trigger the new images/boxes to load.

I cannot find the culprit container setting I need to adjust or include in each media query. OR, something else is going on that I don't understand - I don't know masonry containers at all. I also have seen some suggestions it may have to do with the sticky footer.

```
<?php echo $this->header_part; ?>

<div id="boxcontainerwrapper" class="maxwidth">

<header class="maxwidth">
    <div>
        <h1 class="newest-ideas"><?php echo $this->translate('Latest Finds');?></h1>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="clear mt20"></div>
<div id="boxcontainer" class="event-masonry-container" style="margin-top:-41px;"><?php echo $this->result_data; ?></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
head.ready('items', function(){
    App.loadAjaxData();
});
</script>
<?php echo $this->footer_part; ?>
```

Here are some of the CSS styles:

```
#boxcontainerwrapper { margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; width: 970px; }
#boxcontainer { margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; max-width: 970px;}
```

SOLUTION: The issue was that the column widths of the masonry container were determining the height size, based on the number of images/boxes that were showing but in my css, I was able to display the boxes in 2 columns.  So, the container sized the height based on number of images/boxes but I displayed them based on how I wanted it to look.  I ended up finding the columnWidth settings in my js folder under App.masonryOptions. These allowed me to set the column width for various viewport sizes and adjust css accordingly to either show one or two columns.

Comment: @Red2678, You were so helpful on my last display issue, wondering if you might have an idea what is going on here.  Tx!